# How to keep an input call inside a function/Only call for an input under an if condition?

Tags: python

First attempt at python, apologies. The issue is that when you select 'Exponential', the alpha = float(input('first number')) & beta = float(input('second number')) lines are being read. I thought I sorted this issue out by organizing everything into functions so that these lines wouldn't be called unless the right option was selected. Also tried putting alpha and beta variables under an if statement (the same one that calls multaddsubdiv()) and still the inputs are showing up.

I realize that this code reads really weird but I like the detailed outputs it gives

```
def menu():
    print("Select from the following: ")
    print('Multiplication')
    print('Addition')
    print('Subtraction')
    print('Division')
    print('Exponential')
    global Action
    Action = input("Selected Action: ")


menu()


def multaddsubdiv():
    alpha = float(input("First Number: "))
    beta = float(input("Second Number: "))
    if Action == "Multiplication":
        print('The product of', float(alpha), '&', float(beta), 'Is', float(alpha) * float(beta))
    if Action == "Addition":
        print('The sum of', float(alpha), 'Plus', float(beta), 'Is', float(alpha) + float(beta))
    if Action == "Subtraction":
        print("The difference of", float(alpha), 'Minus', float(beta), 'Is', float(alpha) - float(beta))
    if Action == "Division":
        print("The quotient of", float(alpha), 'Divided by', float(beta), 'Is', float(alpha) / float(beta))


if Action == 'Multiplication' or 'Addition' or 'Subtraction' or 'Division' and not 'Exponential':
    multaddsubdiv()


def exponent():
    gamma = float(input("Base Number: "))
    delta = float(input("Exponent: "))
    print(float(gamma), 'To the Power of', float(delta), 'Is: ', float(gamma) ** float(delta))


if Action == "Exponential":
    exponent()
```

Answer (score 0):

good first attempt.

I cleaned up your code a bit. The first thing I noticed was that you had created a global variable `Action` which does work but isn't really a healthy or 'python' thing to do normally. A better way is to return the variable `Action` from the function like I did. This is safer and keeps the scope of the variable cleaner.

Now back to your main issue. Your `IF STATEMENT` wasn't actually checking if `Action` was equal to one of those items, it was checking if it was equal to the OR of all those items. This might seem a bit confusing. So for now, just remember that (just like maths) there is an operator priority that takes places. In this case, all the "or's" were being done first, and then the == sign. And so the `multaddsubdiv()` function was being called instead of your `exponent()`.

Here's an updated version of your code, now working as it should:

```
def menu():
    print("Select from the following: ")
    print('Multiplication')
    print('Addition')
    print('Subtraction')
    print('Division')
    print('Exponential')
    Action = input("Selected Action: ")
    return Action

def multaddsubdiv():
    alpha = float(input("First Number: "))
    beta = float(input("Second Number: "))
    if Action == "Multiplication":
        print('The product of', float(alpha), '&', float(beta), 'Is', float(alpha) * float(beta))
    if Action == "Addition":
        print('The sum of', float(alpha), 'Plus', float(beta), 'Is', float(alpha) + float(beta))
    if Action == "Subtraction":
        print("The difference of", float(alpha), 'Minus', float(beta), 'Is', float(alpha) - float(beta))
    if Action == "Division":
        print("The quotient of", float(alpha), 'Divided by', float(beta), 'Is', float(alpha) / float(beta))

def exponent():
    gamma = float(input("Base Number: "))
    delta = float(input("Exponent: "))
    print(float(gamma), 'To the Power of', float(delta), 'Is: ', float(gamma) ** float(delta))


Action = menu()

if Action == 'Multiplication' or Action == 'Addition' or Action == 'Subtraction' or Action == 'Division':
    multaddsubdiv()
elif Action == "Exponential":
    exponent()
```